# Namespace has no exported member "User" Angularfire 2

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular5

Service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';


@Injectable()
export class AfService {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  constructor(public afAuth : AngularFireAuth){
    this.user=afAuth.authState;
  }

  loginWithGoogle(){
    const provider= new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

  }
  logout(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

}
```

app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule,AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing-module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import { PagesListComponent } from './pages-list/pages-list.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './login-page/login-page.component';
import {AfService} from './providers/af.service';
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PagesListComponent,
    LoginPageComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [AfService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Error while compiling -

*******Namespace '"/Users/Triathlon/Desktop/cms/cms-app/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'User'.

Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof "/Users/Triathlon/Desktop/cms/cms-app/node_modules/firebase/app/index"'.**

Comment: Did you try `import { User } from 'firebase';`

Comment: Yes, didn't work :/

Comment: What version of the `firebase` npm module is installed?

Comment: --firebase@5.0.1

Comment: Yeah I have that version installed and can import as I stated above. Looking in the `firebase` node module `index.d.ts` file it exports the `User` interface on line 38, so that should be all that is needed. The `User` type is not defined in the `firebase/app` directory so that should not work as you have above. You should be able to import like `import { User } from 'firebase';` and use like `user: Observable<User>;`